# Lock-free programming: reordering and memory order semantics

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, lock-free, memory-barriers

I am trying to find my feet in lock-free programming. Having read different explanations for memory ordering semantics, I would like to clear up what possible reordering may happen. As far as I understood, instructions may be reordered by the compiler (due to optimization when the program is compiled) and CPU (at runtime?).

For the relaxed semantics [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) provides the following example:

```cpp
// Thread 1:
r1 = y.load(memory_order_relaxed); // A
x.store(r1, memory_order_relaxed); // B
// Thread 2:
r2 = x.load(memory_order_relaxed); // C 
y.store(42, memory_order_relaxed); // D
```

It is said that with x and y initially zero the code is allowed to produce r1 == r2 == 42 because, although A is sequenced-before B within thread 1 and C is sequenced before D within thread 2, nothing prevents D from appearing before A in the modification order of y, and B from appearing before C in the modification order of x. How could that happen? Does it imply that C and D get reordered, so the execution order would be DABC? Is it allowed to reorder A and B?

For the acquire-release semantics there is the following sample code:

```cpp
std::atomic<std::string*> ptr;
int data;

void producer()
{
    std::string* p  = new std::string("Hello");
    data = 42;
    ptr.store(p, std::memory_order_release);
}

void consumer()
{
    std::string* p2;
    while (!(p2 = ptr.load(std::memory_order_acquire)))
        ;
    assert(*p2 == "Hello"); // never fires
    assert(data == 42); // never fires
}
```

I'm wondering what if we used relaxed memory order instead of acquire? I guess, the value of `data` could be read before `p2 = ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`, but what about `p2`?

Finally, why it is fine to use relaxed memory order in this case?

```cpp
template<typename T>
class stack
{
    std::atomic<node<T>*> head;
 public:
    void push(const T& data)
    {
      node<T>* new_node = new node<T>(data);

      // put the current value of head into new_node->next
      new_node->next = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

      // now make new_node the new head, but if the head
      // is no longer what's stored in new_node->next
      // (some other thread must have inserted a node just now)
      // then put that new head into new_node->next and try again
      while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node,
                                        std::memory_order_release,
                                        std::memory_order_relaxed))
          ; // the body of the loop is empty
    }
};
```

I mean both `head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` and `head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed)`.

To summarize all the above, my question is essentially when do I have to care about potential reordering and when I don't?

Comment: Notice that #2 would have Undefined Behaviour according to the C++ standard if `int data` was read without a synchronizes-with guarantee that stops the reading thread from looking at it while it's still being written.  That would be the UB kind of data race, since it's not a std::atomic type.  `std::atomic<int>` using `memory_order_relaxed` would avoid UB `data`, and just leave you with a valid (but less useful) program with a garden-variety data race bug. But the string-compare after dereferencing `ptr` would still be a data race, because `std::string` isn't a an atomic / lock-free container.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't really understand why string comparison would be a data race here. In the consumer we are waiting until `p2` is initialized. Then we compare the string. Due to "don't break single-threaded code" rule this order must be preserved. Once we got something in `p2` we are guaranteed to see the pointed data (as you mentioned, on all CPUs except Alpha). The data must be at least as new as the pointer, hence if the pointer is initialized, the data must have already been initialized too. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I meant it's a data race if the writer or reader uses `memory_order_relaxed`, because either of those would allow the pointer to read as non-NULL while the data in the `std::string` class was still being written.  (Note that compiling for a non-Alpha CPU is irrelevant as far as UB or not.  Just like signed integer overflow is UB even when compiling for a 2's complement machine where it has very well defined semantics.)

Comment: The "don't break single-threaded code" rule only means that the thread that wrote it can read it without checking, but every *other* thread can see reordering.  i.e. a single thread sees its own operations in order, but other threads see them happen out-of-order.

Comment: "either of those would allow the pointer to read as non-NULL while the data in the std::string class was still being written" - doesn't it contradict the statement that loading a pointer and then dereferencing it guarantees that the data you get is at least as new as the pointer?

Comment: That only applies to typical weakly-ordered CPU hardware, NOT to the C++ memory model.  And second, "newest" means in order of global visibility, not in program order for the thread doing the storing.  This is why the producer needs to use a release-store to make sure the updated pointer doesn't become visible until after the updated data.

Comment: Put another way:  mo_consume gives you LoadLoad ordering for dependent loads (which you'd think would happen for free, because how can a dereference happen before the pointer value is read, but some specific Alpha hardware found a way to do it under rare conditions).  That doesn't do anything about StoreStore ordering for the producer, which you also need, and which doesn't happen for free on weakly-ordered architectures (and which the compiler can do at compile-time unless you tell it not to).  I think "at least as new as the pointer" way of stating it was just confusing, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For #1, compiler may issue the store to y before the load from x (there are no dependencies), and even if it doesn't, the load from x can be delayed at cpu/memory level.

For #2, p2 would be nonzero, but neither *p2 nor data would necessarily have a meaningful value.

For #3 there is only one act of publishing non-atomic stores made by this thread, and it is a release

You should always care about reordering, or, better, not assume any order: neither C++ nor hardware executes code top to bottom, they only respect dependencies.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the point #2: in which scenario *p2 would be meaningless? Regarding point #3, I understand that it uses release for publishing, but my question was more about the loads (the initial load to `new_node->next` and the load in case of `compare_exchange_weak` failure). Why don't we need acquire order here?

Comment: @mentalmushroom `*p2` was not published for the relaxed reader thread to see. It was published for whoever does acquire. In #3, there is nothing non-atomic that is read from memory, so nothing to acquire.

Comment: If it wasn't published for the relaxed reader, why did `ptr.load()` return a non-zero value? In #3 `new_node` and `new_node->next` are non-atomic, right?

Comment: @mentalmushroom `p2.load` returned a non-zero value because that's what was in `p2`. This is not related to `*p2`. Yes, `new_node` and `new_node->next` are non-atomic. They are not being read from anywhere,  there is nothing to acquire.

Comment: I guess, you meant `ptr.load()` returned what was in `ptr`. But according to the docs `std::atomic<std::string*> ptr` will be zero-initialized, therefore it should always return `nullptr` until something else is stored there. When `p` gets stored it's already initialized to `new string("hello")` and, as far as I understand, initialization of `p` can't be reordered past the store call as long as `p` is the argument (i.e. the store call depends on `p`). Or am I wrong? In #3 the only non-atomic store seems to be in `head->next`, but we don't acquire it, so why do we need release here?

Comment: @mentalmushroom order of events in the producer thread is just for that thread. As for #3, the matching acquire would be in the  pop() member function.